# GoPro 11 video colour fades after export

Tags: video, editing, color-grading, gopro

I recently bought a GoPro Hero 11 Black Camera. It records 5.3K quality videos, which is crips and rich in colour. But whenever I try to edit and export using any known video editor, it simply fades a little and lose its punchy colour. I tried using Filmora X and Powerdirector 19. Both are producing exactly same result and both are capped at maximum 4K resolution. Could anyone tell me how to keep the colour from getting faded? I'm new to GoPro and video editing. Please !